# bc doesn't support log and factorial calculation?

Tags: calculator

Is there any other command line calculator that supports `log`, `n!` calculations? At least `bc` can't do that, it produced a parse error.

It's best if I could use it in a script, e.g `echo '5!' | program`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`bc` supports the natural logarithm if invoked with the `-l` flag. You can calculate the base-10 or base-2 log with it:

```
$ bc -l
...
l(100)/l(10)
2.00000000000000000000

l(256)/l(2)
8.00000000000000000007
```

I don't think there's a built-in factorial, but that's easy enough to write yourself:

```
$ bc
...
define fact_rec (n) { 
  if (n < 0) {
    print "oops";
    halt;
  }
  if (n < 2) return 1;
  return n*fact_rec(n-1);
}
fact_rec(5)
120
```

Or:

```
define fact_it (n) {
  if (n < 0) {
    print "oops";
    halt;
  }
  res = 1;
  for (; n > 1; n--) {
    res *= n;
  }
  return res;
}
fact_it(100)
93326215443944152681699238856266700490715968264381621468592963895217\
59999322991560894146397615651828625369792082722375825118521091686400\
0000000000000000000000
```

To be POSIX compliant, you'd need to write it:

```
define f(n) {
  auto s, m
  if (n <= 0) {
    "Invalid input: "
    n
    return(-1)
  }
  s = scale
  scale = 0
  m = n / 1
  scale = s
  if (n != m) {
    "Invalid input: "
    n
    return(-1)
  }
  if (n < 2) return(1)
  return(n * f(n - 1))
}
```

That is: single character function name, no `print`, no `halt`, parenthesis required in `return(x)`. If you don't need input validation (here for positive integer numbers), it's just:

```
define f(n) {
  if (n < 2) return(1)
  return(n * f(n - 1))
}
```

Comment: Although `bc` can be made to support `n!`, the OP asked for another calculator that already supports such functions.  `bc` is indeed irritating in the fact that you have to google/`man` basic syntax present on any scientific calculator.

Answer (score 5):

[Orpie](https://github.com/pelzlpj/orpie) is *the* calculator for the union set of calculator and command line geeks. It emulates a classic HP RPN calculator, which is of course the only true way to calculate. [It is known](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=72FkbGo78RQ).

If you are a calculator heretic, raised on TIs, Casios, and such, there are [many](http://www.hpmuseum.org/rpn.htm) [RPN](http://edspi31415.blogspot.com/2011/09/rpn-basics.html) [tutorials](http://www.lehigh.edu/~sgb2/rpnTutor.html) online with which you may begin your re-education. [The Orpie manual](https://manpages.org/orpie) will eventually be of some use to you, once you get the RPN Way of thinking down.

To compute 5! in Orpie, just type it as you'd write it: <kbd>5</kbd> <kbd>!</kbd>. You can press <kbd>Enter</kbd> between them to push `5` onto the stack first, but it isn't necessary.

To compute log<sub>10</sub>(5), type <kbd>5</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd> <kbd>'</kbd> <kbd>l</kbd> <kbd>o</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>. You do have to push the `5` onto the stack first in this case, since the next keystroke isn't an operator. That single quote character enters command abbreviation mode, which lets you start typing `log10`, which you can uniquely identify with just the first two characters. (`l` alone gets you the natural log function, `ln` instead.)

As with any RPN calculator, you can get *really* fast with Orpie, with a bit of practice.

Orpie is in the stock Ubuntu repos. FreeBSD includes it in Ports, as `math/orpie`. On macOS, you can install it through [Homebrew](http://brew.sh). Third-party packages may be available for other OSes. Building from source may be a bit of a chore, since it is written in [OCaml](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ocaml), and you probably don't have an OCaml development environment installed. Getting one set up isn't particularly hard, though.

Comment: If you have Mac Ports: $ sudo /opt/local/bin/port install orpie

Answer (score 3):

There's always GNU [Octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), the emacs of command-line calculators (for when you want a complete development environment and programming language built-in to your calculator, and thousands of optional add-ons)

or [R](http://www.r-project.org/) if stats are more your thing.

I mostly just use `bc -l` to get the standard math library loaded...I even have `bc` aliased to `bc -l`.  See Mat's answer for info on defining a factorial function....although the `bc` man page defines it as:

```
define f (x) {
  if (x <= 1) return (1);
  return (f(x-1) * x);
}
```

Checking for <=1 rather than == 1 prevents an endless loop if you happen to feed it a negative number (should be an error) or zero (valid).

Answer (score 2):

My favourite is the lightweight, simple `W-Calc`.
http://w-calc.sourceforge.net

You don't have to look in the manual or manually re-create common functions, like you do with `bc` - the commands are mostly exactly what you'd expect, so just type in what you want and it just works.  Testing as per your question - indeed `log()` & `n!` work as expected.

(Admittedly I haven't heard of Orpie - very well may be a better option.)

Answer (score 1):

Totally overkill, but programming language interpreters are command line calculators after all:

```
$ echo 5 | python -c 'import sys; import math; print math.factorial(int(sys.stdin.readline()));'
120
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this very simply using bc in a loop is below, where w="Prefactorial number" and W="Post factorial number"

```
n=$(( $w - 1 ))
m="$w"
W=$(for g in $(seq $n);do m=$(echo "scale=10;$m*$g" | bc); done; echo "$m")
```