# Como calcular um número fatorial em Bash puro - (Ex.: 5!)

Tags: bash, shell-script, math

Trying to translate:

> What is a basic, elegant and fast way, to write factorial in Bash/in a
>   shell script, purely. (Code) Please make suggestions. (Code)

Tem outra alternativa mais básica/elegante/rápida de como fazer em poucas linhas de código uma maneira de calcular um número fatorial em BASH (Shell Script) puro.

```
Ex.: 5! = 5*4*3*2*1 = 120
```

Essa é minha sugestão:

```
num=5
echo $(($(eval echo {$num..1} | sed 's/ /*/g')))
```

Comment: In English, per favore.

Comment: I can't read most of those words, but if you're looking for a factorial, try [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/409491/factorial-of-certain-numbers-yield-negative-values) or [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44226/bc-doesnt-support-log-and-factorial-calculation) or [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45909/do-shells-support-recursion) or [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41957/how-to-define-a-bc-function-for-later-use)

Comment: I will just mention that Stack Overflow in Spanish is a thing: https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: @dhag This is Portuguese, not Spanish

Comment: @Fox: Whoops. Thanks. Perhaps https://pt.stackoverflow.com/ would be an idea, then.

Answer (score 2):

This works without eval:

```
prod=$(echo {1..5}* 1); echo $((prod))
```

Here is a bash function, which takes an parameter, what isn't possible in the above solution:

```
fak () 
{ 
    echo $(($(seq -s'*' 1 $1)))
}
```

As cas pointed out in the comments, the Shell is limited to 64 bits, for bigger results, bc is worth a try, but that isn't puro, is it? Well - that argument count's for seq too; it's an external program.

```
echo {1..30}* 1 | bc
```

Comment: +1 for the `{1..5}* 1`, but it's probably better to pipe into `bc` rather than use bash's built-in arithmetic.  `bc` can work with integers of any arbitrary precision, while shell has a maxint value (determined mostly by cpu architecture it was compiled on - e.g. 64 bit int on a 64 bit cpu).  For example, `prod=$(echo {1..30}* 1); echo $((prod))` prints `-8764578968847253504` (clearly wrong), while `echo {1..30}* 1 | bc` prints `265252859812191058636308480000000` (presumably correct).

Comment: Yes, bc reaches far wider, while not arbitrary wide - test `echo "9^9^9 | bc"`. And afaik, bash calculated with 64 bits when I still used a 32bit PC, but I'm not 100% sure about that. I don't speak Brazilian/Portuguese, but "em BASH (Shell Script) puro" sounds much like "in purely Bash" doesn't it? (I updated the translation). And the example 5! didn't look that ambitious, too. :)

Comment: the `bc` docs & man page say "arbitrary" so that's what i copied :)

Comment: BTW, piping into `bc` works for at least up to `99999!`.  That took about 5 minutes to run on my machine, which was boring enough to discourage me from trying larger numbers.

Comment: afaik echo "8^8^8 | bc" fails too, but "7^7^7 | bc" should work. :)

Comment: `{1..5}* 1` looks cool until you happen to have a file starting with one of these digits in the current directory:  and `bc` responds with `(standard_in) 1: syntax error`